# How does Windows link a pe file to its signature in a catalog file?

Tags: python, windows, security, certificate, signtool

Running `signtool.exe verify /a /v C:\Windows\notepad.exe` I can see the signature for notepad.exe is in `C:\Windows\system32\CatRoot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}\ntexe.cat`. How does signtool know that is where the signature exists for this pe file?

I am trying to replicate this signtool behaviour in python. Once I have the catalog file I can get the certificate information with the code below but I cannot see how windows links the file to the catalog.

```
import win32com.client
catpath = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\CatRoot\\{F----E}\\nt5.cat"
signedCode = win32com.client.Dispatch('capicom.signedcode')
signedCode.FileName=catpath
signedCode.Verify()
certs = signedCode.Certificates
for cert in certs:
    print cert.Archived
    print cert.IssuerName
    print cert.SerialNumber
    print cert.SubjectName
    print cert.Thumbprint
    print cert.ValidFromDate
    print cert.ValidToDate
    print cert.Version
```

But how do I get which security catalog file the executable is in?

Answer (score 4):

> Disclaimer: the followings is a rough guess based on testing as the exact process is undocumented.
>
> Windows scans through every cat file in System32\CatRoot\{F7--EE}, add them to the [system catalog database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734083%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and roughly sort them by each entry's file hash/tag value.
>
> (revealed by CatRoot2\dberr.txt which contains the log for the database process)
>
> The database is the file System32\CatRoot2\{F7--EE}\catdb. 
>
> Inside catdb, a file hash is followed by its cat file name in CatRoot\{F7--EE}.
>
>  Note the hash excludes PE checksum & Certificate Table Entry. 
>
>  The hash can be obtained from SignTool verify /v or [this](http://www.jensign.com/hash/).

Comment: Is there any way to read/parse the catdb file? Is it an ese db? I can open it once I stop the crypto service.

Comment: @vfxGer Hey you're right it is an [ESE Database](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine_%28ESE%29_Database_File_%28EDB%29_format) as it has a matching file signature. Other than that I have no idea on the file. I dunno any open code library for reading it.

Comment: found an open library, maybe you already know it: [Libesedb](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Libesedb)